# How to Prove Ownership of plugin

Tags: plugin-development, copyright

So I'm considering writing wordpress plugins to sell. Apparently distributing these type of plugins requires you to hand over the source code to the client. What would happen if one of the clients claims ownership of my plugins and starts selling them. How would I prove ownership of my plugin?

For example in VB.Net project your code will be compiled so the end user will not have access to the source. So you can prove ownership by showing your code to the court, while he does not have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t sell the code, you sell support and automatic updates. If your plugin is successful, some people might try to claim the ownership … that doesn’t really matter, they will never be relevant for your business.

If you want to get a legal proof that you are the owner, develop your code with Git from the very first line on, and use [signed commits](https://ariejan.net/2014/06/04/gpg-sign-your-git-commits/).

Comment: This is answer is more complete than mine :) Here's your upvote @toscho

Comment: thanks for the answer toscho. So What advantage does it have to write my code on github rather than be using my own hosting? Can I use signed commits on my own hosting?

Comment: @behnam Git is not Github, both are not directly related. Yes, you can use signed commits in every Git repository, including private repos.

Comment: could a private repository be used as proof of ownership?

Comment: Yes, probably. You can make it accessible in a lawsuit.

Comment: @toscho, what about a self hosted repository (one that I host on my own website). Would that be any good or does it have to be one from the larger providers such as "Github". Becease if its selfhosted I could probably change the source and everything to show incorrect dates and such.

Comment: @behnam You cannot change the history of a repo (easily) with signed commits. The location doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution to this would be to obfuscate your code, other than that, I don't see a solution. This is a problem with every PHP script you purchase online - may it be a plugin or a theme.

Keep in mind though that if you'll want to use an obfuscator, you're also going to need something to decrypt it on the server end (that means extra costs for the client as well as overhead and possibly, better resource requirements from his server).